# Zend 2 Soap Server XML 1.1

Tags: php, xml, zend-framework, soap

How can I get Zend to generate XML 1.1 instead of 1.0 for Soap Server XML's

I have an error in XML parsing becouse of control chars in the content / string of some soap bodys.

As I read [here](http://www.herongyang.com/XML/XML-1-1-Control-Codes-Supported.html) this will be no problem in xml version 1.1.

Right now it seems not possible to determinate version 1.1 instead of 1.0 for Zend Soap, or do I miss something here?

Comment: Please state you exact requirement for XML 1.1. Soap is XML 1.0 based, so it's highly likely you fall into the [X/Y problem here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem). As you speak about control characters, I assume you relate to binary data and therefore close against some SOAP base64 Q&A until you provide exact reference and requirements and it becomes clear this is not an X/Y problem. Additional recommended Q&A: [Should I learn XML 1.0 or XML 1.1?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6260975/367456)

Comment: I can't get the point why this is marked as duplicate.

Comment: @Undercover1989: Have you ever heard about the X/Y Problem? If not, I've left a link in my first comment that is about the duplicate close. I also asked the OP to provide more details (and which kind of details) so that in case it actually is not a duplicate this become clear very fast and the question can be re-opened. Until now, no more detail was provided nor was there a claim by OP that the duplicate is not what he is looking for.

Comment: It was the X/Y Problem (i never heard about such a explanation about this misstake ..). I use base64 encoding / decoding now to avoid binary chars in xml content.